# typescript elegantly enforce a constraint while preserving types

Tags: typescript

so originally to enforce a constraint, i'd just apply an interface like this

```
// this is the constraint
interface Topic {
  [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>
}

// object that must pass the constraint
const topic: Topic = {

  // GOOD: topic methods must conform
  async actuate(a: boolean) {}
}

// BAD: type signature broken
topic.actuate(true)
```

but the problem was that the typings for `topic` became reduced to the lowest-common-denominator, which is the constraint `Topic` — instead, i want `topic` to retain its detailed type signatures for methods like `actuate`

so i found this crappy hacky way to get the best of both worlds:

```
interface Topic {
  [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>
}

type TopicConstraint<T extends Topic> = T

const topic = {

  // GOOD: topic methods must conform
  async actuate(a: boolean) {}
}

// BAD: weird ugly unused type variable constraint hack
// BAD: all topic constraint errors actually land here
type TopicCheck = TopicConstraint<typeof topic>

// GOOD: type signature preserved
topic.actuate(true)
```

is there some more proper way to accomplish the same more elegantly? i don't know how to express this constraint situation in typescript

and yet i can't help but feel there's something special about

```
type TopicConstraint<T extends Topic> = T
```

which might be key... it makes me want to do illegal typescript things like

```
// invalid, but i need something in the same spirit
const topic = TopicConstraint<{
  async actuate(a: boolean) {}
}>

// invalid, but i need something in the same spirit
const topic: TopicConstraint<@self> = {
  async actuate(a: boolean) {}
}
```

i'm searching for a syntax that i can't quite find.. is there a different approach? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to deal with this is not to annotate your variable at all, but let the compiler infer its type.  Then, sometime later, when you use that variable somewhere that expects a `Topic`, you'll get the desired error *there*:

```
const topic = {
    async actuate(a: boolean) { }
};
topic.actuate(true);

const badTopic = {
    oops(a: boolean) { }
}
badTopic.oops(true);

// later ...

function topicTaker(t: Topic) {
    // do something with a Topic
}

topicTaker(topic); // okay

topicTaker(badTopic); // error!
// ------> ~~~~~~~~
// Property 'oops' is incompatible with index signature.
```

So this works, and in some use cases this is really sufficient: you don't actually care if the variable is of the right type until you try to use it.

But what if this error check is too far from the object declaration to be helpful to you?

---

Well, if you want to catch the error earlier, you can do what I usually do and make a *helper function*:

```
const asTopic = <T extends Topic>(topic: T) => topic;
```

This constrained generic identity function just returns its argument at runtime.  But at compile time it will require that `topic` is assignable to `Topic` without actually *widening* it to `topic`.  Instead of annotating your variables, just initialize them to the return value of the helper function:

```
const topic = asTopic({
    async actuate(a: boolean) { }
});

topic.actuate(true); // okay

const badTopic = asTopic({
    oops(a: boolean) { } // error!
//  ~~~~
// void is not assignable to type Promise<any>
})
```

You can look at `asTopic()` two ways: as a **replacement for annotation** to avoid widening (i.e., use `asTopic()` instead of `: Topic`), or as an **early warning** that your object is not of the type you want (i.e., `asTopic()` acts like a `topicTaker()` that you call immediately at the creation site instead of deferring it).

Re-reading the question: this `asTopic()` helper function is probably the thing you were feeling around for with your `TopicConstraint`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsEsGdThSBTUBjA9gO1uATgIbRbgBQx4yeAZgWqgCoYAO0aoA3qaD6ANoBrZAE8AXKFx5iAcwC64gBQA6FQTzTY4glmF9ZASlABeAHygACngwBbOMgA824SdIBfUqWoBXLGnDRsCBY2BgIhPAVwcSZWNEMuXlAQUAATDAkbZCgZUAB3aChQAlAYtjcPLAJrZFhmOlQAEWQAGwJhZBTObl5MHHAg2OMuxMSCWGFfIr8vAkoFAnEAIwwMZuRteNB3RNcAbm6ecGC0JTpwGbn8L2R9fYP0bFxQRYIU0vYjYZGeFeZYeaWKzWG04W3u214LzexyUv3+Vxud0SR1ioXCkWOtySYAwAjaHmRxzRVAUUPeWOSVCseAAhPdkgBaJnMswAP3ZHPZ9LAlhYVHAwlAAHI4UKEPBiJhrHV-Is1nkCpAEFgUsgAB4SaDSSrnPDIJTlUiVaq1eolXLpBI9R79MbvIb2BigdWUFXwd4mDGxaKGUwDNhI619f0fIqwd4KK3fMYTdhnC7IAHPIHrLCbCE8Vy3Am8FFsU7TWaJhEUnF44Q5ni9J5k45DO3HSP3RJwpPLVap9PY514al0xLJUCc7mgABuGGgnUQWAwttgsC1lTlqCOEGEzFQvNssAcThcO30HlcQA)

Comment: absolutely fantastic! i've adopted this `asTopic` pattern, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a no-op function that has the relevant generics in the argument so it constrains in place:

([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsEsGdThSBTUBjA9gO1uATgIbRbgCwAUMeMngGYFqoAqGADtGqAN4WigDaAa2QBPAFyhceYgHMAuhIAUAOlUE8M2BIJYR-OQEpQAXgB8oAAp4MAWzjIAPDpGmKAXwq0ArljTho2KDIOF54yCzsaA5MQQAe1FgAJvARHKaK4GwcEkwGPOR8fGHgoVgQWWgA3O4UFCCgGABGAFbIfkgE4KA2XrigrASw8FComDj4RCQUY32ZkSZBIWGpaIr5vKD1AOIA8jsAIhJzHN3IUBjJ3b1dY7QYeDYbgyK+oAwlnciKBBKNGBgAG2QOiMXA85DcBiAA))

```
// this is the constraint
interface Topic {
  [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>
}
function ensureTopic<T extends Topic>(topic: T){
    return topic;
}

// object that must pass the constraint
const topic = ensureTopic({

  // GOOD: topic methods must conform
  async actuate(a: boolean) {}
})
```

related: [Use function interface to ensure parameters but infer more specific return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056008/use-function-interface-to-ensure-parameters-but-infer-more-specific-return-type)