# Self type keys of a Record

Tags: typescript

```
type Foo = Record<string, number>

const one: Foo = {
    a: 0,
    b: 0
}
const two: Foo = {
    c: 0,
}
// doesn't need to be typed
const foos = {
  one,
  two
}

const getFoos = (scope: keyof typeof foos) => (key: keyof typeof foos[typeof scope]) => foos[scope][key]

const scope = getFoos("one")
scope("x") // no error because `key` is of type `string`
```

As you can see above, the `key` argument is of type string while I'd like it to be typed following the key of the `scope`.

For example if `getFoos("one")` is called, the type of the arguments of the returned function (`key`) should be `"a" | "b"`.

The type `string` is surely coming from the `Record` in `Foo`, but I assume there's a way to type it like I've described above.

Comment: If I answer this question it will look like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64127811/2887218), so I'm inclined to close the whole question as a duplicate.  Replace `Topic`/`topic` in that answer with `Foo`/`foo` and see if it addresses your needs.  If not, please elaborate on what is still missing.

Comment: @jcalz I'm unable to solve my issue with the answer you sent. I've simplified the question above a lot (probably too much) just so it's clearer where the issue is, but let me edit it and give a bit more context.

Comment: If I take that other answer and replace `Topic` with `Foo` and plug your code in I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/DWK9KN), which looks like what you want, unless I'm missing something.  The advice is "don't annotate `one` and `two` as `Foo` if you don't want their types widened to `Foo`".  Please let me know if there's anything else you need here, or if there's a different issue here I am not seeing.

Comment: Well, indeed it's what I want. I hoped I didn't have to use this `asFoo` function on every object. But it's working, thanks! I'll close this question.

Comment: And note that your `getFoos()` function needs to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) in order for the particular key passed in to affect the type of the returned function, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/qWJ7rw).

Comment: If you don't want to use `asFoo` on every object you can use `asFoos` on the collection instead, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/vwjXlm).  It's a tradeoff between doing extra work and getting the error close to the bad object's definition, or doing less work and delaying errors until something tries to use the bad object.  If you don't mind getting the error all the way in something that calls `getFoos('three')('d')` and expects a `number`, then you don't need any helper functions at all.