# Interface property name from a constant configuration object

Tags: typescript

I have an external service that varies it API payloads slightly depending on the installation due to custom fields with numerical id's. I've been rolling with the first example until now, but now I want clean up the configuration files a bit. Is there any way to group my constants together in an object without getting a type error?

```js
    // No Problem
    const DEV_WIDGET_FIELD_NAME = 'customfield_723'
    interface ApiPayload {
      [DEV_WIDGET_FIELD_NAME]: WidgetType // No problem
    }

    // A computed property name in an interface must refer to an 
    // expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
    interface WidgetType {
      a: string;
    }

    interface ConfigType {
      WIDGET_FIELD_NAME: string
    }

    const DEV_CONFIG: ConfigType = {
      WIDGET_FIELD_NAME: 'customfield_723'
    } as const
    interface ApiPayload {
      [DEV_CONFIG.WIDGET_FIELD_NAME]: WidgetType
    }
```

Edited: I didn't have the ConfigType in my original example. Taking it out makes this work as I expected.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, [see this Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wjkG1N).  Can you give more information? Are you using some old TS version?

Comment: Oops, I oversimplified my example I think. When adding a type to the config object it causes an error, but I think I can work around this. [edited playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrACYHMJgCoCeADigN4CwAUMsnAFzIDOYUoWA3FQL5VWiSxEKAMIB7EDGBZCJZBWpoAkgBEA4gFE8AfQBii9QBllWgHIBBALLqGzViCzdelBOObJl6gGpbhAeRN6qgxiElIyKAC8clQ0qCoa2nqGxuZWDADkCACuzKIAtpIQADYYWgDsAEwAzOnctIzILiDMfODQ8EjIZkTAAApwBEWicBjRCgDaHt5+AYqqAHRxapq6+kamluoAugzo2Ljh3EA)

Comment: Sure, annotating it as a wider object type explicitly throws away that information. Why do you need to annotate it at all?  Seems like this might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64127535/2887218) if your actual problem is that you really want to *check* that `DEV_CONFIG` is of the right type without *widening* it to that type

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jcalz comments and some experimentation, it looks like annotating the `DEV_CONFIG` constant with a type made things go a bit wonky. Removing that makes the constant object work as expected.